# Why is generic parameter not required to be set explicitly?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I am confused how this private function `readValue` is working:

```scala
private def readValue[T](path: String, v: => T): Option[T] = {
  try {
    Option(v)
  } catch {
    case e: ConfigException.Missing => None
    case NonFatal(e)                => throw reportError(path, e.getMessage, Some(e))
  }
}
```

The parameter `v` is a function that returns `T`, and `T` is set when you call it like:

```
readValue[String]
```

But [in the following snippet](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala#L177), I see `readValue` being used with no generic parameter type `T` explicitly defined:

```
def getInt(path: String): Option[Int] = readValue(path, underlying.getInt(path))
```

Why is this not

```
readValue[Int](path, underlying.getInt(path))
```

i.e. with the `Int` set explicitly? How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underlying Config object 'underlying: Config' has method getInt with return type Int, and this information provides enough evidence to infer type parameter for readValue, so you don't need to define it explicitly

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html - example with id function should be helpful

Comment: btw, with intelliJ, is it possible to figure out the type of a function that doesn't explicitly have the type defined?

Comment: @Blankman It is. See [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Show+Type+Info+Action) for information on that.